# Karaf freezing with log at debug when connecting with client

Tags: apache-karaf

With Karaf 4.1.3 and Karaf 4.1.4 when I connect as a client.sh (with the log level set to debug) and perform a log:tail I get the following...

2018-01-05 13:38:00,348 | DEBUG | 0]-nio2-thread-1 | Nio2Session                      | 48 - org.apache.sshd.core - 1.6.0 | handleCompletedWriteCycle(Nio2Session[local=/127.0.0.1:8101, remote=/127.0.0.1:50379]) finished writing len=68

screams out on to the console, and unless I control C the whole karaf container hangs and in the server window I get the following message:

2018-01-05 13:37:58,819 RMI Scheduler(0) ERROR Recursive call to appender PaxOsgi 
2018-01-05 13:37:58,819 RMI Scheduler(0) ERROR Recursive call to appender PaxOsgi 
2018-01-05 13:37:58,819 RMI Scheduler(0) ERROR Recursive call to appender PaxOsgi 
2018-01-05 13:37:58,819 RMI Scheduler(0) ERROR Recursive call to appender PaxOsgi

This is with a clean unzip running oracle 1.8 on both windows and ubuntu.

Any ideas?

Comment: afaik this has been answered on the karaf mailinglist:
https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/76a749b6603030611a8d5032715db0926b9782e0adc4b2ccbc2f3ed8@%3Cuser.karaf.apache.org%3E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed a bug and ticket raised:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-5559